# rsync job no longer making incremental backups

Tags: ubuntu, rsync

I have a simple rsync script that does a monthly backup from my server to an attached USB hard drive. After a year of working correctly (copying only those files that have changed or been added) it has decided to copy every single file.

It is making its decision to copy on datetime stamp.  I use the -t switch to preserve the time stamp when copying.  I have checked with ls -l and cannot see any reason why it copying the files.  I used the -i switch to see if I could get any extra info on why the files were copying but drew a blank.

The server is running Ubuntu Desktop 20.04 patches are up to date)

The script is

```
rsync -r -v -t  /home/stephen/BackupShare/stephen /home/stephen/USBdata/MyBook/Leia
```

`/home/stephen/USBdata` is the point at which I "attach" the USB drive. It's formatted as NTFS.

Clearly something is making it think that the target is out of date but I cannot see what else I can try.  It is taking hours to run when a couple of weeks ago it was taking a few minutes.  The only changes over that period were Ubuntu patches

Would welcome any suggestions for further investigation.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for taking an interest.  NTFS.  The drive used to be on a Windows PC

Comment: Did the start of the failure coincide with a jump in local time (eg. the summer/winter switch that some countries use)

Comment: Thanks.  For that suggestion.  I pretty sure i ran it successfully after day light savings started in October but will check.

Comment: You said you looked at -i output.  Please show that information along with `stat` output for source and destination file for one of the failures.

Comment: Hi Guys, I think I have sussed the issue.   I had a Western Digital "My Disc" mounted as the back up drive.  That usually auto mounts at boot.  Somehow it failed and I failed to see a diagnostic.  That's why it was copying everything because it was copying the data to the drive I was trying to back up instead of the USB disc!!!.  When I did a df -h earlier today I saw that i had far less free space on the drive that I thought.  That was the important clue.  I as soon as I have checked that this is the issue, i will write that as the answer.  Thanks everyone for responding

Comment: Please see answer for, well, answer to my little issue.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for responding.  In fact this WAS NOT an rsync issue.  In fact it was a hardware issue.  Somehow the USB drive became disconnected from the server.  When the rsync script ran, it ran against a mount point that no longer existed.  So instead of seeing the destination, it saw an empty directors so started copying everything.  Unfortunately by the time I started investigating, it had copied enough for it to be difficult to tell by visual inspection that it was copying to the source drive rather than the target USB drive. As soon as I ran df -h I realised what must have happened as I had 100s of GB less than i thought I had free on the server drive.